# Else statement in JavaScript based upon media query / viewport OR 'Retina'-fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, retina.js

I'm creating a website for a photographer. Sadly, to maintain quality, pictures serving should be equal at least the viewport of the user. Therefor, on Retina devices such as the new Macbook Pros, there should be images of about 1800x2880px. Too bad, these load very slowly.

I've currently got a dynamic script that simply loads thumbs and the full picture when clicked on.

The HTML code, for a thumb (and when clicked on, immediately the full size):

```
<a  href="#"
    data-flare-title="All-my-Loving"
    data-flare-width="375"
    class="multiple color"></a>
```

And the Javascript that automatically links the thumb src, and the A href, and some more tags:

```
$(function(){

$('#container #portfolioOverview a').each(function(){

var $link = $(this),
    title = $link.data('flare-title') + '.jpg';
    imgTooltip = $link.data('flare-title');
    imgTip = imgTooltip.replace(/-/g, ' ');
    imgWidth = $link.data('flare-width') + 'px';

$link.attr('href', 'images/portfolio/full/' + title);
$link.attr('data-flare-bw', 'images/portfolio/blackwhite/' + title);
$link.attr('data-flare-thumb', 'images/portfolio/thumbs/' + title);
$link.attr('data-flare-scale', 'fitmax');
$link.attr('data-target', 'flare');
$link.attr('data-flare-gallery', 'portfolio');
$link.addClass('tip');

$link.attr('data-tip', imgTip);

$link.append($('<img>', {
  src     : 'images/portfolio/thumbs/' + title,
  height  : '250px',
  width   : imgWidth
}));

});

});
```

This line: `$link.attr('href', 'images/portfolio/full/' + title);` links the correct full picture to the thumb. However, all these full images have a resolution of about 2800x1800px. These will also load for screens with a resolution of 1024x768, which results in awful, unnecessary slow loading times for smaller screens

**Solution wanted**:
As far as I could think of, this could simply be either a **Retina JS script** or a **Else statement**.

As the Retina JS script will automatically pick the "*@2x.jpg" image in the /images/portfolio/full/ folder, and ignore them for non-retina devices, While the ELSE statement will check if viewport is larger than 1920x1080. If confirm: Serve images from the folder 'images/portfolio/2x' instead of 'full', while 'else' would serve from the default full folder.

Please comment if I'm unclear. Thanks in advance!

**Note:** This should apply to ALL devices running a screen resolution of that above 1920x1080, not only Apple's devices

Comment: `var retina = window.devicePixelRatio > 1;` - `retina` will be `true` if the device is retina enabled, `false` if not.

Comment: @ahren how does this apply to Samsung's and other brands with 2560x1440 and up displays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you don't use any approach of responsive image techniques? More information you can find on http://responsiveimages.org/ If you use a polyfill like https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/srcset-polyfill you are ready for the future.

Another approach is to minimized the image quality by increasing the dimensions of the images. Sounds strange, but it works: http://www.netvlies.nl/blog/design-interactie/retina-revolution I used this technique sometimes and in the result images are sharp even at retina displays.

Comment: I was aware of the blogpost written @ Netvlies, however.. Even after reading it twice, over the past month, I didn't understand that much of it. Think I should give it another look.

Those other two I'll look at. Didn't knew them. Thanks! - Comment or answer again with new solutions. If this fills my problem, you know what button i'll click :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can find the solution to your problem here. I will not copy and paste the solution. The basic idea is to use a custom attribute for serve a high res image on high res display like retina.

http://drew.roon.io/retina-images-that-respond

Comment: Seems pretty interesting - Although I could be wrong but isn't that exactly what Retina.JS does?

Comment: I did not know retina.js. It looks interesting.